# ¿Tengo un problema con actualización de datos con update, case y joins en postgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, base-de-datos, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Tengo las siguientes tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien en la tabla "liquidaciones" en la columna nivel, necesito tengo que actualizarla con esto:

Si el empleado es de estrato 1 y sus ingresos menores o iguales al valor de Tope T1 su nivel_sisben es 0

Si el empleado es de estrato 1 y sus ingresos menores o iguales al valor de Tope T2 su nivel_sisben es 1

Si el empleado es de estrato 1 y sus ingresos menores o iguales al valor de Tope T3 su nivel_sisben es 2

Si el empleado es de estrato 1 y sus ingresos mayores al valor de Tope T3 su nivel_sisben es N

---

yo tengo esto:

```
begin;

update liquidacion set nivel =
(case
when estbarrio = '1' and suelcar <= (select valor_top from topes where codigo_top = 'T1') then '0'

when estbarrio = '1' and suelcar <= (select valor_top from topes where codigo_top = 'T2') then '1'

when estbarrio = '1' and suelcar <= (select valor_top from topes where codigo_top = 'T3') then '2'

when estbarrio = '1' and suelcar > (select valor_top from topes where codigo_top = 'T3') then 'N'

end)

from

empleados join barrios on barrio=codbarrio join cargos on empleados.codcar=cargos.codcar

select * from liquidacion;

rollback;
```

pero no funciona :((( necesito ayudaaaa:)) por favor :)

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. 1. Respondiendo a la pregunta de tu título: _sí_. ¡No hay necesidad de agregar signos de interrogación innecesarios! Además, en el título debes indicar brevemente cuál es el problema. 2. No agregues estructuras de tablas, o mensajes de error, o código, como imagen. [Eso es mala idea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). 3. ¿Qué tienen que ver mysql y sql server si la pregunta es acerca de Postgresql? Elimina las etiquetas no relacionadas. Y por sobre todo: **¿cuál es el problema?** Lee [ask].